# Retrieve items that do not have an empty array list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have a list of items, those items have some attributes one of which is an array list. The array list may be empty or not.

How do i retrieve the items from the list that their array list is not empty

Comment: Share example data and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `select` together with `present?` (or `reject`/`blank?`):

```
items = items.select{|x| x.array_attribute.present?}
```